# c# How to reference a dynamically created component?

Tags: c#, object

I have some code that create a few components on the click of a button. Something like this.

```
CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
chk.Top = 50;
chk.Left = 50;
chk.Text = "Check Box Test";
chk.Name = "chkTest"
this.Controls.Add(chk);
```

So how do I use this component. For example I tried this but got and error saying the component didn't exist. I just want to get their values.

```
if(chkTest.Checked)
{
//Do this
}
```

Please help.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: Where does the chkTest variable come from? You can definitely retrieve it (the dynamically created control) from the Controls collection and then cast it to a CheckBox to access it's properties.

Comment: Of course you can't do that. A control does not magically appear as a member of a form (or whatever class you are using it from). You would have to use a placeholder variable `Form1 { ... private ComboBox chkTest; ... }` or as **Dave** suggested extract it from the `Controls` collection outside the scope of the `chk` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either create a member variable in your class called chkTest that you can use later, or retrieve it on the fly from the Controls collection when needed, like so:

```
CheckBox chkTest = (CheckBox)Controls["chkTest"];
if(chkTest.Checked) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Use `CheckBox chkTest = Controls["chkTest"] as CheckBox;` - there is no implicit conversion from `Control` to `CheckBox`.

Comment: @Jaroslav Jandek thanks, I've updated the post for that.  Also, since we expect it to be a CheckBox, there's no need to use the as operator -- a direct cast will suffice.

Comment: @siride: unless you make a typo and add `chkTest` as `ComboBox` or whatever, in that case, it should fail anyway. So direct cast is OK.

Comment: Why don't we code a bit more defensively. It takes all of 10 seconds to add code (null check with as operator) that protects use from typos.

Comment: Right, but what are you going to do if it's null?  Better to throw an exception (which is a big warning flag) instead of just eating it and having the program silently behave incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about the control when it is checked or unchecked, use an event.

```
chk.Checked += new RoutedEventHandler(CheckBox_Checked);
chk.Unchecked += new RoutedEventHandler(CheckBox_Checked);

private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkBox = sender as CheckBox;
    if (chkBox.IsChecked.Value)
    {
        // Do this...
    }
}
```

Make sure to unsubscribe from the event handlers when you are finished with them.

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing chkTest but you created chk.

Comment: It doesn't matter what name i call it. I put chkTest because that is what name a gave it.

Comment: @Ash - where are you declaring and assigning a value to the variable chkTest?

Answer (score 0):

You could declare the Checkbox as a member variable of your page. Then you would be able to access it more easily.

Class MyPage
{
   CheckBox chkTest;

// then in page load
   // chkTest = new CheckBox(); ...

}

Comment: Doing that thats up memory which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko: that's a micro-optimization that won't really save you that much and may in fact result in you using more memory and CPU time to find the control from the collection.

Comment: How do you expect that this saves memory?

Comment: I thought the question was about how to help you reference the control. I don't see anything about saving memory.

Comment: @Dave White: it saves 4 bytes in an object that is likely to have very few instances.

Comment: @siride I understand why and how much memory will be saved. I was asking the question so that Ash could answer with his thoughts. :)

Comment: The example was shorted to fit on OS. In my actual application i have 100 componant of which only 10 may be used depending which option they choose. Therefore i dont want to be creating something which takes up memory that wont be used.

Comment: It's not that much memory.  The variables are only references, that is, 4 bytes each.  Say you had 10 instances of this form class, you'd save 4 * 10 * 100 = 4000 bytes.  That's less than a page and certainly insignificant compared to the amount of memory on a system likely to run winforms apps.

Comment: Interesting post on the memory optimization topic! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378536/does-a-variable-itself-consume-memory/3380361#3380361
Maybe we don't know what we're talking about and we should leave it to experimentation and the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((Controls.Items["chkTest"] as CheckBox).Checked)
{
// Do this
}
```

should work, but it's not pretty to look at. :)

You could declare it as a variable, then use it like you did:

```
CheckBox chkTest = Controls.Items["chkTest"] as Checkbox;
if (chkTest.Checked)
{
// Do this
}
```

Look on this handy page for ways to manipulate and access your Control's collection of items:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection_members.aspx

Comment: You should ensure that chkTest is not null before using it when you are using the as operator.